# Validation Rule for Picklist and Multi picklist

Tags: picklist, validation, validation-rule, multi-select

`Option__c`(picklist) This is picklist field which contains values (Yes/No) and default as Yes.
This field(`Option__c`) should only be mandatory, when the field `State__c`(multi picklist) has selected as NY.

I have tried a Validation rule, it looks something like this,

1)

```
  IF( INCLUDES( States__c , "NY"),
   CONTAINS(Text(Option__c),null),FALSE)
```

2. ```
   IF(CONTAINS(TEXT(Option__c), "YES:NO") , IF( INCLUDES( States__c , "NY"), false, true), false)
   ```

Both are not working and also not allowing me to save on any conditions.
Any suggestion please,
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How about `AND(ISPICKVAL(State__c, 'NY'), ISBLANK(Option__c))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this validation rule.

```
AND( INCLUDES( States__c ,'NY'), ISBLANK( TEXT( Option__c ) ) )
```

Comment: Yes, above rule is working. Thanks SaiPraveen and TSmith